# No video when waking from sleep

Tags: 18.04, graphics, suspend

After not having much luck on [the ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2402054), I decided to repost my question here and maybe get some answers.

When I wake my computer from suspend, I do not get any video output. The computer itself *is* functioning, as I can SSH into it and shut it down or do whatever. One time after pressing the power button to wake it quickly after entering sleep mode, I did manage to get the video output working, but then i got no response from the USB devices (mouse, keyboard).

Also worth mentioning is that the computer wakes from sleep in Windows 8.1 just fine. I'm using the `nvidia-driver-390` from ppa.

**My specs are:**

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- MEM: 15.6GiB (2x8 Corsair DDR4-3200)
- CPU: Intel Core i7-8700K @ 3.70GHz
- GPU: GeForce GTX 1080 (Gigabyte WINDFORCE)
- MB: Asus PRIME Z370-A
- PSU: Antec HCG850 ATX
- 500GB nvme SSD and 2TB sata HDD